# program column is null in v$session

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AWH_TOOLS_TRG
AFTER LOGON ON HRMS.SCHEMA
DECLARE
v_prog sys.v_$session.program%TYPE;
v_pro  varchar2(250);
BEGIN
SELECT upper(program) INTO v_prog
FROM sys.v_$session
WHERE  audsid = USERENV('SESSIONID')
AND  audsid != 0
AND  ROWNUM = 1;
v_pro := SUBSTR(upper(v_prog),0,INSTR(upper(v_prog),'.')-1);
IF UPPER(USERENV('TERMINAL')) NOT IN ('DESKTOP-U186KO5','WLSRV') THEN
          IF UPPER(v_prog) LIKE '%TOAD%'      OR 
             UPPER(v_prog) LIKE '%T.O.A.D%'   OR
             UPPER(v_prog) LIKE '%SQLNAV%'    OR
             UPPER(v_prog) LIKE '%PLSQLDEV%'  OR
             UPPER(v_prog) LIKE '%BUSOBJ%'    OR
             UPPER(v_prog) LIKE '%EXCEL%'     OR
             UPPER(v_prog) LIKE '%SQLPLUS%'   OR
             UPPER(v_prog) LIKE '%FRMBLD%'    OR
             UPPER(v_prog) LIKE '%RWBUILDER%' 
          THEN
          RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20983, '" '||v_pro||' "'||' not allowed... Please contact DBA...!!!');
          END IF;
END IF;
END;
```

program column is not showing any data during query.
How can i resolve this issue???

Comment: The client application provides that information. My application can pretend to be any application it likes. That trigger provides no security whatsoever. Use proper grants to prevent users from accessing the data they shouldn't. This approach is **not** going to work.

Answer (score 1):

The value for `PROGRAM` is set by the client application.  I'm not sure if it is set before or after a login.

I'll have to verify - I suspect something like Tomcat can set `PROGRAM` to `NULL`.

## Other Notes

- `SYS_CONTEXT( 'USERENV', 'CLIENT_PROGRAM_NAME' )` might be a better method.
- The value *usually* comes from the name of the executable.

  - IIRC - there is a function within the drivers to set the value to something else.
- A simple `RENAME`/`mv` will bypass your `LOGIN TRIGGER`.

Limiting login acceptance of users based on the value of `PROGRAM` is a futile effort.

Comment: I tried select SYS_CONTEXT( 'USERENV', 'CLIENT_PROGRAM_NAME') from dual but the error occured ORA-02003: invalid USERENV parameter